# Extracting file lines assigning to a vector

Tags: rust

Playing around with Rust and getting stuck on a basic assignment error.

Here's my code:

```
fn parse_file_lines(filename: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut file_lines: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    if let Ok(lines) = read_lines(filename) {
        lines.for_each(|line| match line {
            Ok(l) => {
                // perform some logic here...
                file_lines.push(&l)
            }
            Err(_) => todo!(),
        })
    }

    return file_lines;
}

fn read_lines(filename: &str) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>> {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    Ok(io::BufReader::new(file).lines())
}
```

Which is returning this compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `l` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:38
   |
14 |     let mut file_lines: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
   |         -------------- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `file_lines`
...
17 |             Ok(l) => file_lines.push(&l),
   |                      ----------------^^-
   |                      |               | |
   |                      |               | `l` dropped here while still borrowed
   |                      |               borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                      argument requires that `l` is borrowed for `'1`
```

I know my [scopes are off](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0597.html) somehow but can't figure out why - it's been a long day

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::io::Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/io/struct.Lines.html) yields owned `String`s, not borrowed `&str`s, and thus you cannot drop them and store a reference to them in a `Vec`.

Instead, store the owned `String`s in the `Vec`:

```rust
fn parse_file_lines(filename: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut file_lines: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    if let Ok(lines) = read_lines(filename) {
        lines.for_each(|line| match line {
            Ok(l) => {
                // perform some logic here...
                file_lines.push(l)
            }
            Err(_) => todo!(),
        })
    }

    return file_lines;
}
```